Gorenstein Rings of given multiplicity
Is there any classification of Gorenstein rings of a given multiplicity?
Any reference article is appreciated.

I think that the paper https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/dimension6.pdf by Poonen includes the classification up to multiplicity 6 for artinian Gorenstein $k$-algebras over an algebraically closed field $k$. Is it true that there are infinitely many for multiplicity 7? Poonen's paper deals with all artinian $k$-algebras, not just the Gorenstein ones.

@RichardStanley Sir, This article is really helpful. I am great thankful to you.
